# Is tangential nutrition off topic

Tags: discussion, scope

[How much garlic in the mountain kitchen?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/1699/how-much-garlic-in-the-mountain-kitchen)

To me this question reads more like "What is a good daily dose of garlic?" with a "oh and i'll be in the woods" thrown in to make it on topic.

(remember, vote up if you agree it's off topic, and down if you think it's on topic)

Comment: Definitely off-topic.

Comment: Yes, more about cooking than outdoors, I've asked the cooking mods if they'd like it.